# Why this always gives -1?

Tags: summation

The following sum always gives -1 if k is undefined but different values when k is defined. Why?

```
Sum[DifferenceDelta[n^k, n], {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Dirichlet]
```

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until what you've observed has been confirmed by other users.

Answer (score 8):

Because:

```
DifferenceDelta[n^k, n]
```

gives:

```
n^k + (1 + n)^k
```

with `k` unspecified

```
Sum[  n^k,{n,1,Infinity}]
```

is (generically)

```
-Zeta[-k]
```

while

```
Sum[ (1+n)^k,{n,1,Infinity}]
```

is

```
-1 + Zeta[-k]
```

hence

```
Sum[DifferenceDelta[n^k, n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives `-1`.

The reason for this is that this is the answer for all Complex `k` for which the sum converges.